# String Length is different in Java Application and in Oracle Database

Tags: java, html, string, character-encoding, oracle11g

I am trying to insert one description filed into oracale database using html form in JAVA.
The database field length i have set to 650.
Now, I am checking before submitting the form if the description filed length is more than 650, if so then i am inteneded to show a pop up saying maximum limit is exceeded.
The problem is, I am putting below text in the description filed, which is 640 Characters in length.When i am submitting the form, it passes the 650 character length checking as expected but it throws me exception from the database saying..

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12899: value too large for column "Column Name" (actual: 690, maximum: 650)
```

---

> Description i am putting

```
asdfghjklzxcvbnmasdfghjklzxcvbnmasdfghjklzxcvbnmasdfghjklzxcvbnmasdfghjklzxcvbnm

asdfghjklzxcvbnmasdfghjklzxcvbnmasdfghjklzxcvbnmasdfghjklzxcvbnm63457612901

asdfghjklzxcvbnmasdfghjklzxcvbnmasdfghjklzxcvbnmasdfghjklzxcvbnm63457612901asdfghjklzxcvbnmasdfghjklzxcvbnmasdfghjklzxcvbnmasdfghjklzxcvbnm63457612901

asdfghjklzxcvbnmasdfghjklzxcvbnmasdfghjklzxcvbnmasdfghjklzxcvbnm63457612901

asdfghjklzxcvbnmasdfghjklzxcvbnmasdfghjklzxcvbnmasdfghjklzxcvbnm63457612901 asdfghjklzxcvbnmasdfghjklzxcvbnmasdfghjklzxcvbnmasdfghjklzxcvbnm63457612901

asdfghjklzxcvbnmasdfghjklzxcvbnmasdfghjklzxcvbnmasdfghjklzxcvbnm63457612901122344adddadsd
```

I don't understand why it has been 690 characters where as i have put only 640 Characters String !

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: @SeyfülislamÖzdemir Do you know any encoding, in which these 640 characters are represented with 725 bytes?

Comment: Oracle columns can have a _byte_ length or a _character_ length. I'm guessing yours is byte-length.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Not exactly for the given description above as they are actually all ASCII characters. But its possible for some strings, depending on what kind of characters the string include http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-width_encoding

Comment: @SeyfülislamÖzdemir I know about encodings, and - yes, you are right - it will have to do with encoding. But OP explained that he tried to store the shown description, which is somewhat strange as these 640 characters should be 640 bytes (in ASCII, in UTF-8, in ISO-8859-1). They would be 1280 bytes in UTF-16. But I don't see any encoding that makes them 725 bytes! Maybe the error message and the description don't match.

Comment: @Ani can you dump the sql query generated?

Comment: I see a JEE tag in there - if this is the result of some kind of ORM generating the SQL then you could use something like log4jdbc to log the exact query that is being sent to the database.

Comment: @SeyfülislamÖzdemir,@Seelenvirtuose yes I will Provide you the SQL query generated. But before that I have modified my question. It was actually becoming 690 characters instead of 725.I am really sorry to misguide you. Still it is 690 Characters where as i have put only 640 characters

Comment: use google and search for NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS. @GriffeyDog is right.